# How to insert in data base from a span with on click, and how can i change after click for second time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

```css
body
{
    vertical-align: center;
    margin: auto ;
    width: 90%;

}
div
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 300px ;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218) ;
    background-color:  rgb(218, 218, 218) ;
    padding: 8px ;
    text-align: center;
}
input
{
    float: right;
}
div:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(190, 180, 180);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html >
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inscrivez sur notre site</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CentreInteret.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#"method="POST">
            <h2>Quels sont vos interets ?</h2>
            <?php
               include("connexion.php") ;
               $affichage = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT libelle From centre_interet");
               $i=0;
               while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($affichage))
               { 
                   echo "<div  id=\"$i\"  onclick=\"myFunction$i()\" >".$data['libelle'] ."</div>" ;
            ?>
                   <script>
                    var array= [] ;
                    function myFunction<?php echo "$i" ?>() 
                    {
                        
                        document.getElementById( <?php echo "\"$i\"" ?>).style.background = "powderblue";
                        
                        
                                          
                    }
                   </script>
            <?php
                   $i++;
                }
               
               mysqli_close($link); 
            ?>     
           
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="soumettre" value="Suivant"/>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on span it changes the color, but when I click again it doesn't go back to it's normal css.
I don't know how to get the values of the clicked span and insert them into the data base.

Here is my code
HTML:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhdZQ.png)

and CSS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO51x.png)

Please help. I didn't study JS so I don't know a lot about it.

Comment: put your code into the post as a snippet to let us help you, don't post your code as an IMG

Comment: Burham B. Soliman i added it now

Answer (score 0):

ok i'll give you a hint about classList toggle,

so you can add anew class in your css with `background: new-bg-color;`, then call it in your script instead of setting background , so using the same button twice will toggle between original class and the new one.

just try the snippet it would help u achieve your goal,

```js
function text() {
var box = document.getElementById('example');
box.classList.toggle('box');
}
```

```css
div {
height: 100px;
width:200px;
background:powderblue;
}

.box {

  background-color: coral;

}
```

```html
<div id="example" class="">test</div>

<input id="button" type="button" name="toggle" value="toggle" onClick="text()" />
```